# Eclipse could not export android project to gradle based

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, export

I followed [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) tips and could no pass the problem that it displays windows with Exported modules, and even I tick "Force overiding of exsting files", nor finish does not bring any effect. Even we tick all submodules for main project it still blocked.

Any ideas what might cause that problem?

[image: official documentation]

Comment: I would suggest to import the Eclipse project directly in Studio. Its import feature is more advanced than the export to gradle in ADT.

Comment: Sure it is, just despite the dependencies even on AS it does not work explicitly well. I'll have to deal with gradle then, hope it will benefit future. Anyway sollution for upper issue would be appreciated for further ones.

Answer (score 0):

You have one project without name, that already indicates some incorrect state.

Generally, you should have `build.gradle` in every project and `settings.gradle` in main project.
[Gradle for Eclipse page](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/) may help

[image]

When you have gradle build passed, then you are ready to import into Android Studio as well.